Different class used on maximizable PrimeVue dialog
I'm currently using PrimeVue Dialog. Now I want to use a different class/style based on whether the dialog is maximized or not. For the sake of simplicity, let's say i want to make the text bold or red when the dialog is maximized. How do i do this?
Code example:
<template>
    <!-- OTHER STUFF HERE -->
    <Dialog v-model:visible="true" maximizable modal header="TEST" :style="{ width: '50rem' }">
        <div class="formgrid grid">
            <div class="field col-12">
                <!-- use this when dialog is not maximized -->
                <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>

                <!-- add new class/style when dialog is maximized -->
                <p class="font-semibold" style="color: red">Lorem ipsum.</p> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </Dialog>
</template>



In summary, I want to use v-bind:class or v-bind:style based on whether the dialog is maximized or not, but the problem is I don't have access to the dialog maximized attribute.

You can see that there's p-dialog-maximized class when it's maximized, you can add styles to it

What I finally did is:
<script setup>
    const dialog = ref()
    const dialogMaximized = computed(() => dialog.value.maximized)
</script>

<template>
    <div v-if="dialogMaximized">
        ...
    </div>

    <div v-else>
    </div>

    <Dialog ref="dialog" maximizable ...>
        ...
    </Dialog>
</template>

In summary, I create the ref for dialog, create a new variable to get the maximizedState of the dialog, and then use it in the <template>
It works fine for now, but i will leave this question with no accepted answer since someone with more expertise may give a better answer.
